# harbor migrate to another virtual machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, harbor

I want to migrate harbor content which runs by docker-compose to another VM,I don't want to replicated /data/ directory, it's `too big`, so I copy `/data/database` directory to another VM, harbor dashboard only shows projects, so it didn't migrate images and their tags. Obviously, I didn't copy it completely, but I didn't know what directory I need to copy.

harbor docker-compose.yml is as follows:

```
version: '2'
services:
  log:
    image: goharbor/harbor-log:v1.7.1
    container_name: harbor-log 
    restart: always
    dns_search: .
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - DAC_OVERRIDE
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - /var/log/harbor/:/var/log/docker/:z
      - ./common/config/log/:/etc/logrotate.d/:z
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:1514:10514
    networks:
      - harbor
  registry:
    image: goharbor/registry-photon:v2.6.2-v1.7.1
    container_name: registry
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - /data/registry:/storage:z
      - ./common/config/registry/:/etc/registry/:z
      - ./common/config/custom-ca-bundle.crt:/harbor_cust_cert/custom-ca-bundle.crt:z
    networks:
      - harbor
    dns_search: .
    depends_on:
      - log
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:  
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "registry"
  registryctl:
    image: goharbor/harbor-registryctl:v1.7.1
    container_name: registryctl
    env_file:
      - ./common/config/registryctl/env
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - /data/registry:/storage:z
      - ./common/config/registry/:/etc/registry/:z
      - ./common/config/registryctl/config.yml:/etc/registryctl/config.yml:z
    networks:
      - harbor
    dns_search: .
    depends_on:
      - log
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:  
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "registryctl"
  postgresql:
    image: goharbor/harbor-db:v1.7.1
    container_name: harbor-db
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - DAC_OVERRIDE
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - /data/database:/var/lib/postgresql/data:z
    networks:
      - harbor
    dns_search: .
    env_file:
      - ./common/config/db/env
    depends_on:
      - log
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:  
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "postgresql"
  adminserver:
    image: goharbor/harbor-adminserver:v1.7.1
    container_name: harbor-adminserver
    env_file:
      - ./common/config/adminserver/env
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - /data/config/:/etc/adminserver/config/:z
      - /data/secretkey:/etc/adminserver/key:z
      - /data/:/data/:z
    networks:
      - harbor
    dns_search: .
    depends_on:
      - log
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:  
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "adminserver"
  core:
    image: goharbor/harbor-core:v1.7.1
    container_name: harbor-core
    env_file:
      - ./common/config/core/env
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - ./common/config/core/app.conf:/etc/core/app.conf:z
      - ./common/config/core/private_key.pem:/etc/core/private_key.pem:z
      - ./common/config/core/certificates/:/etc/core/certificates/:z
      - /data/secretkey:/etc/core/key:z
      - /data/ca_download/:/etc/core/ca/:z
      - /data/psc/:/etc/core/token/:z
      - /data/:/data/:z
    networks:
      - harbor
    dns_search: .
    depends_on:
      - log
      - adminserver
      - registry
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:  
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "core"
  portal:
    image: goharbor/harbor-portal:v1.7.1
    container_name: harbor-portal
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
      - NET_BIND_SERVICE
    networks:
      - harbor
    dns_search: .
    depends_on:
      - log
      - core
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "portal"

  jobservice:
    image: goharbor/harbor-jobservice:v1.7.1
    container_name: harbor-jobservice
    env_file:
      - ./common/config/jobservice/env
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - /data/job_logs:/var/log/jobs:z
      - ./common/config/jobservice/config.yml:/etc/jobservice/config.yml:z
    networks:
      - harbor
    dns_search: .
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - core
      - adminserver
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "jobservice"
  redis:
    image: goharbor/redis-photon:v1.7.1
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
    volumes:
      - /data/redis:/var/lib/redis
    networks:
      - harbor
    dns_search: .
    depends_on:
      - log
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "redis"
  proxy:
    image: goharbor/nginx-photon:v1.7.1
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    cap_drop:
      - ALL
    cap_add:
      - CHOWN
      - SETGID
      - SETUID
      - NET_BIND_SERVICE
    volumes:
      - ./common/config/nginx:/etc/nginx:z
    networks:
      - harbor
    dns_search: .
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 4443:4443
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
      - registry
      - core
      - portal
      - log
    logging:
      driver: "syslog"
      options:  
        syslog-address: "tcp://127.0.0.1:1514"
        tag: "proxy"
networks:
  harbor:
    external: false
```

I would very appreciate it if you guys can tell me what directory I need to replicated or other ways to migrate harbor to another virtual machine.

Comment: were you able to migrate harbor to new VM using replication?

Answer (score 1):

The database only contains metadata. To make everything work well, a simple way you can try is configuring the **replication** policy to replicate all the images in the source harbor to the destinated harbor.

Replication is one of the powerful features Harbor provided.